# Docker failing for OpenLDAP build on m1 chip

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap

Trying to build an OpenLDAP service in Docker but keep getting the below issues in the logs which cause it to exit. This may be because I'm on an m1 chip (as seen in the `newosproc` error. Can someone confirm this is the case?

```
No certificate file and certificate key provided, generate:
/container/service/slapd/assets/certs/ldap.crt and /container/service/slapd/assets/certs/ldap.key
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x54c470, 0x9)

runtime stack:
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:530 +0x90
runtime.newosproc(0xc820034000, 0xc820043fc0)
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Will do, question has been updated

Comment: It sounds like this is a symptom of trying to run some x86_64 images under emulation on ARM processors. See e.g. the discussion in https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6137 and in linked issues.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was looking at an old installation guide in my case. To fix this, I ran `osixia/openldap:1.5.0` which worked vs previously I was running `osixia/openldap:1.1.9`